# Why won't topic messages get dequeued?

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I want to ask a question about the topics of activemq.

I entered admin page of activemq and found that messages enqueued will never be dequeued in topics even if consumers had been written correctly.  That means the all published messages will be permanently kept in ActiveMQ.

Will these message lead to a memory leak?  Is there a solution that could make consumed messages dequeued?

[image]

Comment: what do u mean by 'never be dequeued'. Messages are in 'Ready' state or in 'Processed' state? as you said that Consumers has done with it correctly.

Comment: could refer to this picture above, we can see the enqueued message count in blue area, and dequeued message count in red area, the questions is that I had consumed all the messages in red area, but they all still be kept in this area, I want them appear in the red area.

Comment: picture still not displaying... anyways... check your message retention policy for the destination

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may need to config your session with the right way. 
connection.createSession(Boolean.FALSE, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE)
ActiveMQ will only marked the message to Dequeued by your code if you use a transaction or Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE

Comment: Mine still shows zero even with this. It also shows zero consumers even though I have a working one that has not yet been closed.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveMQ supports advisory messages which allows you to watch the system using regular JMS messages. Currently we have advisory messages that support:
consumers, producers and connections starting and stopping
temporary destinations being created and destroyed
messages expiring on topics and queues
brokers sending messages to destinations with no consumers.
connections starting and stopping

Advisory messages can be thought as some kind of administrative channel where you receive information regarding what is happening on your JMS provider along with what's happening with producers, consumers and destinations. When you look at a broker via JMX you will see the advisory topics prefixed with **ActiveMQ.Advisory..**

Details:http://activemq.apache.org/advisory-message.html